# How can I set a char variable to the KeyCode of Input.GetKey?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to make a cheat code system. I had an array of chars. I want to assign whatever input the player puts in to that char, and then ill change the index to the next char and repeat with that. At the end I want to combine all the chars together to a string and see if that's a cheat code. If it is then the player will get a powerup or whatever.

I basically want the char to be whatever button I press. Is there any better way to do it that's not like this:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
{
CodeAttempt[index] = 'a'
index++;
}
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
{
CodeAttempt[index] = 'b'
index++;
}
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
{
CodeAttempt[index] = 'c'
index++;
}
```

And so on?

Comment: why you want array? and not string?

Comment: Take a look at this example: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/convert-an-enum-to-a-string/  Basically convert your KeyCode.A to string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Input.anyKeyDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-anyKeyDown.html) and [Input.inputString](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-inputString.html) (case-sensitive):

```
private void Update()
{
    if( Input.anyKeyDown )
    {
        foreach( char c in Input.inputString )
            CodeAttempt[index++] = char.ToLowerInvariant( c );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you a genius? Seriously though thank you so much haha. I wasn't aware of Input.inputString but I tested it out and it's super helpful! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Unity doesn't have built-in `KeyCode` to `char` mappings.

I found a Gist that has a `char` to `KeyCode` dictionary. Simply swap the keys and values and you should be good to go: https://gist.github.com/b-cancel/c516990b8b304d47188a7fa8be9a1ad9

I don't want to put the code here in the answer since it is too long, but I made a fork in case the original Gist goes down: https://gist.github.com/starikcetin/62506e691ecd465159a235fb7acb44f0

---

**Edit:** Why don't you keep your cheat code in the form of a `KeyCode` array? Then you don't have to deal with chars.