# How to save the keycode of a pressed key?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a hangman game, but I don't quite know how to handle the input. I would like to have a string that I could then compare to the word the player is guessing.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
{
  answer = "A"
}
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
{
  answer = "B"
}
```

I know I could just repeat this 13 times but I was wondering if there is a better way of doing things.

Comment: Do you want an alternative for the above code? I couldnt understand what you try to achieve

Comment: How about `Console.ReadKey`?

Comment: See [C# How to translate virtual keycode to char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318777/c-sharp-how-to-translate-virtual-keycode-to-char)

Comment: @Flydog57I think he is working with unity and he wont work with the console

Comment: @MrJami Yeah I would love an alternative to my code. And yes I work with unity.

Comment: @JonasH That is kind of similar to what I'm after it just seems really complex, will it work in unity though?

Comment: @Jan Hrubec, I have no idea about unity. Perhaps [InputString](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-inputString.html) is better to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting my answer from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68696337/how-can-i-set-a-char-variable-to-the-keycode-of-input-getkey/68698925#68698925):

> You can use
> [Input.anyKeyDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-anyKeyDown.html)
> and
> [Input.inputString](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-inputString.html)
> (case-sensitive):

```
private void Update()
{
    if( Input.anyKeyDown )
    {
        foreach( char c in Input.inputString )
            answer += char.ToUpperInvariant( c );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a far better solution

Answer (score 2):

I actually don't use Unity, but one option is to create `Dictionary` that maps key codes to strings. Then loop through that:

```
var codes = new Dictionary<KeyCode, string> {
    {KeyCode.A, "A"},
    {KeyCode.B, "B"},
    ....etc
};
...
foreach(var code in codes)
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(code.Key)) {
        answer = code.Value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I will definitely try this.:)